# Tables truncated when using bigquery api (buffer size issue?)

Tags: google-bigquery, buffer, gdelt

I am running the following:

> bq query --format=csv SELECT GKGRECORDID, DATE,SourceCommonName,DocumentIdentifier, V2Persons, V2Tone, TranslationInfo, from [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned]where V2Persons like "%Orban%" and _PARTITIONTIME >= TIMESTAMP("2016-11-09") and _PARTITIONTIME < TIMESTAMP("2016-11-11")' > outputfile.csv

This should return a table with roughly 1000 rows (which I get when I use the normal bigquery interface in the browser).  However, when I run this using the api, it will only return 100.

It seems like an issue with the size of the buffer, but I thought I'd ask if there was something that could be done on the bigquery side (for example, a way to send query output in several chunks) to remedy this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line you can specify how many rows to be returned, defaults to max 100.

```
bq query -n 1500
```

Please be aware that maximum return size is 128MB compressed regardless of rows requested.

Comment: Thanks Pentium10--I'd missed that when looking through --help.